Archer GRC - Multiple values is calculated value list
Is there any way of selecting multiple values in a calculated field?
IF(TRUE,VALUEOF([List],"A","B","C"))

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Use something like this:
COMBINEVALUES(
IF([A_SOMETHING]=X, VALUEOF([A]."1"), NO VALUE(),
IF([B_SOMETHING]=Y, VALUEOF([A]."2"), NO VALUE(),
...keep checking for each value in a dedicated IF ...
)
Good luck!

Give this a shot
IF(
 CONTAINS(ANY,[Food Type],VALUEOF([Food Type],"Fruit")),
 VALUEOF([Food],"Apple","Orange","Banana")
)

